# Have eslint only show fatal errors?

Tags: javascript, eslint

I would like to silence all style warnings and only be alerted when there is a major leak in my code, like a missing bracket, or a referenced var that doesn't exist. Is there a rule that can be inserted into eslint.json to quiet everything except fatal errors?

Comment: lint _is_ for checking _style_

Comment: Whether or not it's for style it does also show fatal errors. Not sure why this is being downvoted.

Comment: yeah, idk either; seems legit at least...

Comment: This question need upvote! I quite agree with you  ! Did you find any solution or make a plugin list only show fatal error?  If true, could you share it ?

Comment: I don't have a solution unfortunately

Comment: any solution to this yet?

Answer (score 151):

You can use `--quiet` option to show `error`-level only, like
`eslint --quiet "*.js"`

https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

```
Handling warnings:
 --quiet                        Report errors only - default: false
```

Comment: also nice with angular `ng lint --quiet`

Comment: ty bro
Not sure why the answer is not accepted by the requester @max-phillips

Answer (score -5):

You can use the [`"eslint:recommended"`](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#using-eslintrecommended) config that ships with ESLint. It enables rules that catch common errors but doesn't enforce any specific style.

Comment: It does, such as `Expected parentheses around arrow function argument. `, `Unexpected block statement surrounding arrow body. (arrow-body-style)'`

Comment: @Mithril check your config, you must be including something in addition to `eslint:recommended`. If you look at the [rule list](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/#ecmascript-6), neither of the rules you mention (`arrow-parens` and `arrow-body-style`) has the checkmark that indicates the rule is enabled in `eslint:recommended`.